# В Django 3.2 неправильно работает функция now()

Tags: python-3.x, django, datetime, django-model, gunicorn

Для приложения авторизации в проекте Джанго вычисляю в модели юзера срок истечения действия созданной для него временной ссылки, которая направляется на использованный при регистрации имейл:

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils import timezone

class AuthUser(AbstractUser):
    ...
    activation_key_expires = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.localtime(timezone.now()) + USER_EXPIRES_TIMEDELTA
    )
```

По непонятной мне причине значение атрибута пользователя activation_key_expires оказывается равным не времени создания пользователя, а времени, когда последний раз выполнялся рестарт сервиса gunicorn3.service, который на проде обслуживает приложение. Звучит как-то безумно. Но так и есть. Как это можно объяснить и как исправить такое поведение?

Первоначальная реализация была с помощью отдельной функции:
**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils import timezone

def get_activation_key_expires():
    return timezone.localtime(timezone.now()) + USER_EXPIRES_TIMEDELTA


class AuthUser(AbstractUser):
    ...
    activation_key_expires = models.DateTimeField(
        default=get_activation_key_expires()
    )
```

Результат одинаковый

Comment: Причина вполне понятна — значение по умолчанию для поля вычисляется в момент создания поля, то есть ровно в момент старта сервиса. Вынесите вычисление в отдельную функцию и в default запихните эту функцию

Comment: Честно говоря, она изначально и была вынесена в отдельную функцию, но результат ровно тот же. Поле создается в момент создания экземпляра класса, то есть совсем не связано с моментом запуска сервиса gunicorn

Comment: Покажите, как конкретно была реализована функция и как она использовалась

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: `default=get_activation_key_expires()` -> `default=get_activation_key_expires`. Сейчас вы сохраняете конкретное время (одно для всех записей), а будете вызывать функцию в момент создания поля конкретной записи: "If callable it will be called every time a new object is created.".

Comment: `default=lambda: timezone.localtime(timezone.now()) + USER_EXPIRES_TIMEDELTA`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо - сработало. Проклятые скобки)